# QWheelEvent::angleDelta() возвращаемое значение

Tags: c++, qt5

В Qt 5 появилась [функция](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwheelevent.html#angleDelta):

```
QPoint QWheelEvent::angleDelta() const
```

Она возвращает угол поворота колёсика мыши. Почему она возвращает QPoint, а не int или хотя бы double/float ? Как из этого QPoint'а получить число, на сколько условных единиц повернулось колёсико мыши?

Comment: Видимо потому, что у некоторых мышек бывает два колеса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Удалось выяснить, что это сделано для мышей с двумя колёсами (вертикальное и горизонтальное), для обычных мышей дельту прокрутки колёсика можно получить так:

```
int delta = evnt.angleDelta().x();
```

Вторая компонента QPoint'а будет нулевая.